# order between two gesture recognizer when using gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:

Tags: objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UIScrollView`, and I added a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to it.

I want to use both the `scrollView.panGestureRecognizer` (the default one) and my custom recognizer.

So I overrided the function `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` to YES, and I have both `panGestureRecognizer` called.

My problem is that I need to first call my custom recognizer, and the default one after.

In the documentation, I read :

> In the default behavior, touch events in a multitouch sequence go from one gesture recognizer to another in a **nondeterministic** order until the events are finally delivered to the view (if at all).

Is there a way to have both recognizers active in a **deterministic** order ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using:

```
- (void)requireGestureRecognizerToFail:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
```

You can call this on the `UIScrollView` pan gesture recognizer to make sure your custom recognizer will be called first.